# Suddenly lost the System menu option from Magento Admin Panel

Tags: magento, menu, system, admin

I am using Magento CE 1.9.1.
Everything was working well a while ago and all of a sudden, the "Systems" menu from the admin panel navigation menu disappeared.
I cleared the "var" folder manually but still the problem is the same.
When I googled around, I do not see any one getting this weird error and am sure there is something wrong am doing which am not able to figure out.
Will appreciate if someone can assist on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to your root magento:
app/etc/modules

Here you have to enable the disabled modules again ->

Open the specific xml-module-file, in your favorite notepad editor e.g:

{namespace}_{module}.xml

-> Find the line false
Change false > true and SAVE and upload file back to server.

Repeat this on all the disabled files and empty cache and try login/logout.

Let me know how is works.

Answer (score 1):

To Resolve this issue, you will have to do debugging as follow:

Step 1: Disable all module in local and community folder

First, disable the whole module in local and community folder.

> > For disabling local modules, please follow this tutorial link

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/quick-tip-disable-all-local-modules-at-once/

> > For disabling community modules, please follow below tutorial link

http://blog.onlinebizsoft.com/magento-quickly-disable-all-community-extensions/

After that check your admin section. if all things are working fine. then undo all changes above.

And now for disabling all module's of local and community folder.

- Go to app/etc/modules
- Disable the module

Step 3: When you will find which module has an issue, resolve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Go to yourwebsite/magento/downloader/ ( Magento Connect )

Re-install all

Mage_Core_Adminhtml
Interface_Adminhtml_Default 
Mage_All_Latest
Mage_Core_Modules

I dont know which one did it, but I reinstalled all of them and i worked!